# Does Oracle (RDB in general?) take a snapshot of the table affected by DML?

Tags: database, oracle, consistency, dml

## Objective

To understand the mechanism/implementation when processing DMLs against a table. Does a database (I work on Oracle 11G R2) take snapshots (for each DML) of the table to apply the DMLs?

### Background

I run a SQL to update the AID field of the target table containing old values with the new values from the source table.

[image: Target and correlated source table]

```
UPDATE CASES1 t
SET t.AID=(
  SELECT DISTINCT NID
  FROM REF1
  WHERE
    oid=t.aid
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM REF1
  WHERE oid=t.aid
);
```

I thought the 'OLD01' could be updated twice (OLD01 -> NEW01 -> SCREWED).

[image]

However, it did not happen.

[image]

### Question

For each DML, does a database take a snapshot of table X (call it X+1) for a DML (1st) and then keep taking snapshot (call it X+2) of the result (X+1) for the next DML (2nd) on the table, and so on for each DML that are successibly executed? Is this also used as a mechanism to implement Rollback/Commit?

Is it an expected behaviour specified as a standard somewhere? If so, kindly suggest relevant references. I Googled but not sure what the key words should be to get the right result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

## Update

Started reading Oracle Core (ISBN 9781430239543) by Jonathan Lewis and saw the diagram. So current understanding is the UNDO records are created in the UNDO tablespace for each update and the original data is reconstructed from there, which I initially thought as snapshots.

[image: REDO & UNDO]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, if you ran that update twice in a row in the same session, with the data as you've shown, I believe you should get the results that you expected.  I think you must have gone off track somewhere.  (For example, if you executed the update once, then without committing you opened a second session and executed the same update again, then your result would make sense.)

Conceptually, I think the answer to your question is yes (speaking specifically about Oracle, that is).  A SQL statement effectively operates on a snapshot of the tables as of the point in time that the statement starts executing.  The proper term for this in Oracle is read-consistency.  The mechanism for it, however, does not involve taking a snapshot of the entire table before changes are made.  It is more the reverse - records of the changes are kept in undo segments, and used to revert blocks of the table to the appropriate point in time as needed.

The documentation you ought to look at to understand this in some depth is in the Oracle Concepts manual:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/part_txn.htm#CHDJIGBH

Comment: Thanks for the link. So it looks the CR cloning also applies to the update by the Update DML (in the question) itself. In my understanding, the SQL picks up a row from t (CASES1) and does SELECT from REF1 with t.aid. The SELECT part with t.aid is actually retrieving data from the reconstructed CR block, which will not be affected the UPDATE part of the SQL. Is this correct?

Comment: And I suppose creating UNDO block occurs at the beginning of each SQL statement. For example SQL 1, 2, 3 creates UNDO 1, 2, 3 respectively. Perhaps Savepoint refers to UNDO (N).

Comment: To your first comment - essentially, yes. The entire UPDATE statement will not see changes made after it starts executing, even its own changes.  This includes the subquery, as it is all one statement.

Comment: Undo blocks are not created when statements begin executing.  Undo data is generated as individual data blocks are modified by statements, while they are executing.  Undo data is basically a record of the data that existed before the change; but only of portions of the table that are actually modified.  (This could potentially be the entire table, but it also could be much less.  The undo data stored is proportional to the amount of actual changes made to the table data.)